# Algorithm for Keyword based Recommendation

Tags: java, struts2, recommendation-engine

I am currently creating a web application that allows users to upload photos, then add tags to them(around 5 tags) what I ideally want is to generate a recommendation based on the tags used by the user on the a picture. what is the simples algorithm I can do to achieve such task? or are there any framework or recommendation engine that will fill my need, if so what is it?

Comment: no. like youtube , soundcloud or amazon.

Comment: Does a user enter a tag and then you want similar tags to be recommended? Or do you want the picture to be analysed and then tags recommended based on that?

Comment: I want the picture to be analysed and then tags recommended based on that

Answer (score 0):

There are some journal that can help you about tag recommendation I haven't read it all but I think the graph based tag journal is easier to understand

there are many journal you can find here -> [Link](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=amazon%20tag%20recommendation&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart&sa=X&ei=fWp_Uc6YD8usrAeUxYGoBQ&ved=0CCsQgQMwAA)

I hope that can help you :)

Comment: @user962206 sorry fixed now :)

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, the most naive strategy is to consider this as a type graph problem (vertices are photos and tags are edges). First link each picture to a list of tags. This requires maintaining a Map from PhotoId to List(). Then Also keep a map between tags to users, which is a Map from string to List(). Now for highest similarity find all pictures which share all five tags, or which share 4 tags, or which share 3 tags. In order to do so first pick an arbitrary tag for a particular photo and then find all corresponding users which also have that tag. Now just see which of those users also share the other tags of interest. You can very this methodology to include a photos neighboring tags as well, it's really up to you.

Comment: any idea  or sample code of how I am going to implement this?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what web framework you are using or database. It isn't hard if you just want an in memory representation, but I imagine you're planning on persisting things to the database, in which case its dependent on the database query language as well as the web framework you are using. Could you provide more details on this.

Comment: I am currently using Hibernate as my ORM and MySql for my database. and Struts2 for my mvc